# i5, 6GB RAM and Android 3.0-3.2 emulator still unsuable (cannot start any app)?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-3.0-honeycomb

I do not know what to do. I purchased a new laptop, hp pavillion i5 6GB RAM, started Android 3.2 emulator and it **is still as slow as unusable!!!**

It's not that it is slow, it's that I **cannot do anything**.

I set 1GB of RAM, disabled camera on emulator and run it. When I click on Applications, they first load for 30s and then I am not able to start any app, not mine, not default ones. All I can do is return to desktop and open Applications menu.

I see people complain that the emulator is slow and I am not even able to make it run. What is worse, my laptop eats games like a sandwich, but it chokes with Android emulator 3.2. The same is with Android 3.0 emulator!

Can anyone help me set up the emulator so that I can run it on my machine?

PS. if you want, I will record a video and post it to visually see what I am talking about.

Comment: Android 3.0 emulator isn't optimize even if you have a good configuration. Buy an Android phone or Tablet !
But now the Android 4.0 emulator is better

Comment: @Guillaume You mean, I use Android 4.0 to test my tablet app and I set an emulator to tablet screen size???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not know what to do. I purchased a new laptop, hp pavillion i5 6GB RAM, started Android 3.2 emulator and it is still as slow as unusable!!!

The Android emulator uses a single core. If you had gone with a Core i7 with Turbo Boost, that would have helped. Your Core i5 is not an especially powerful CPU on a per-core basis.

The Android 3.x emulators also do all graphics purely in software (no hardware graphics acceleration) and convert ARM instructions to x86 on the fly.

> Can anyone help me set up the emulator so that I can run it on my machine?

Start by using the Android 4.0 emulator, with the latest Android development tools. This uses your desktop's GPU for graphics rendering, and it helps performance a bit.

If that proves insufficient, you can start switching to x86 emulator images if you are not doing NDK development (where you will tend to want to test on ARM). At the moment, the only official x86 image is for 2.3.3, but [there is an unofficial one for 4.0.3 built from the AOSP](http://blog.testobject.org/2012/04/giving-your-android-emulator-boost.html) that runs exceptionally fast (at least on Linux, haven't tried it on Windows).

Comment: Thanks for a great advise, as always! Emulator 4.0 and 4.0.3 are working fine under MDPI and I use them to test new apps. Do you say that I create new emulator 4.0 or 4.0.3 with a resolution of a tablet? The other guy mentioned 4.0 emulator but did not elaborate.

Comment: @sandalone: "Do you say that I create new emulator 4.0 or 4.0.3 with a resolution of a tablet?" -- yes. WXGA is a common 10.1" tablet resolution and is available in the emulator.

Comment: THAAAAAAAAANKS A LOT!!! Guys this works like a charm and it's so fast that I am afraid to touch buttons :). I wish I can give you 10 upvotes, no 100, no... ;)

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion to you would be to change the "ADB Connection Timeout (ms)" in Eclipse under Window->Preferences->Android->DDMS.  I am using a HP Pavillion 486 laptop, and was really struggling with the emulators.  I changed the default timeout value from 5000 ms (5 sec) to 60000 ms (1 minute).  This didn't solve all of my problems, but it did help in the startup of both the emulator and my applications.